# In PHPExcel, when I try to create excel file with large number of rows(approx=20000) and download it is not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpexcel

Small number of rows work well and download is possible. Any help? I Get alert in error func in ajax call. Is there any issue with JS or memory related issue.

```
PHP Code :

    require_once './Classes/PHPExcel.php';
    require_once './Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    
    // Writing to excel sheet, approx 20000 rows
    
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    ob_start();
    $objWriter->save("php://output");
    $xlsData = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $response =  array(
    'op' => 'ok',
    'file' => "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,".base64_encode($xlsData),
    'data' => $outfilename.'.xls'
    );
    die(json_encode($response));
```

JavaScript Code :

```
$.ajax({
      url: "mypage.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType:'json',      
      data:
      {
        rpttype:"0"
      },      
      success: function(data)
      {
            var $a = $("<a>");
            $a.attr("href",data.file);
            $("body").append($a);
            $a.attr("download", data.data);
            $a[0].click();
            $a.remove();
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
      {
        alert('Error in call.');
      }
      });
```

Comment: If you get a memory related error, you might've reached the memory limit. Set `ini_set("memory_limit", ###);` before  starting to create the file - You'll need to find out what value to set instead of the `###`.

Comment: @Gil, Tried it but not working. I logged the process and found out that writing to excel is working but it seems the code that output the download excel throws memory limit error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you encoding the file into base64? And then further encoding it into json? You don't need to do that in order to get the file. I would guess the base64 is the main suspect in taking all the memory.

Comment: Following are the traces: Date & Time :: 11/22/2021 10:40:59 am |  | Writing Start
Date & Time :: 11/22/2021 10:41:06 am |  | total record :18150 & totalsheet :1
Date & Time :: 11/22/2021 10:41:08 am |  | salesinvoice_all
Date & Time :: 11/22/2021 10:44:22 am |  | Writing Ends
Date & Time :: 11/22/2021 10:44:22 am |  | Peak memory usage: 1380.25 MB

Comment: @Gil, following is the error: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Out of memory (allocated 1791229952) (tried to allocate 12320745 bytes)

Comment: base64 is notorious for inflating data so no wonder you've reached such a high memory usage.  Use the `header()` method to send the file as is , without any of the encodings.

Comment: @Gill, tried your last suggestion but not working, same memory issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: facing same exactly issue  @hirenpatel any help ?